# If $Q^* = Q^{-1}$, then is it necessarily true that $(I - Q)( I + Q)^{-1} = (I + Q)^{-1} (I - Q)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $Q$ is unitary, and $I$ is the identity matrix, and $(I + Q)$ is invertible, do the matrices $(I - Q)$ and $(I + Q)^{-1}$ commute?

If so, is there a simple proof of this fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but this is independent of $Q$ being unitary. Suppose that
$$(I+Q)(I-Q)=(I-Q)(I+Q).\tag{*}$$
If $I+Q$ is invertible, we can left-multiply and right-multiply the above equation by $(I+Q)^{-1}$ to obtain the desired equality,
$$(I-Q)(I+Q)^{-1}=(I+Q)^{-1}(I-Q).$$
Therefore, it is sufficient to establish $(*)$ for an arbitrary matrix $Q$. Expanding $(*)$, we get
$$I-Q+Q-Q^2=I+Q-Q-Q^2,$$
which is trivially true for any matrix $Q$.